# how do I pass multiple column names dynamically in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am writing a python function that will do a leftanti join on two dataframe,  and the joining condition may vary. i.e. sometime 2 DFs might have just one column as unique key for joining, and soemtime 2 DFs might have more than 1 columns to join on.

So, I have written the below code. Please suggest what changes should I make

```
def integraty_check(testdata, refdata, cond = []):
    df = func.join_dataframe(testdata, refdata, cond, "leftanti", logger)
    df = df.select(cond)
    func.write_df_as_parquet_file(df, curate_path, logger)
    return df
```

here the parameter `cond` may have 1 or more than 1 column names as comma separated.

So, hwo do I pass the dynamic list of column names when I am calling the function?

Please suggest what would be the best way to achieve the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use python's Unpacking Operator ([PEP 448](https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/))

```py
df = df.select(*cond)
```

You can find more examples on how to use the asterisk operator:
[Packing and Unpacking Arguments in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/)